# How to control parent element border color when form evaluates empty required input?

Tags: html, css

I want *.inf__drop-area* div border become red and focus on it when form is evaluated and **required** input field inside this div is empty.
https://jsfiddle.net/oLdw7mxp/

```
.inf__drop-area {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 280px;
    background-color: #e7ebf3;
    border: 2px solid #0058ff;
    padding: 0 45px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}   

<form>
  <div class="inf__drop-area">
      <span class="inf__hint">drop file here</span>
      <input type="file" multiple="" name="files" accept="image/*" required>
    </div>
    <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

Is there any CSS solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would capture the click event and check for the length of the files inside the input.

```js
function validate(e){
    if(filebx.files.length == 0){
        droparea.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```css
.inf__drop-area {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 280px;
    background-color: #e7ebf3;
    border: 2px solid #0058ff;
    padding: 0 45px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="inf__drop-area" id="droparea">
      <span class="inf__hint">drop file here</span>
      <input type="file" id="filebx" multiple="" name="files" accept="image/*" required>
    </div>
    <button type='submit' onclick="validate()">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, but js solution seems clumsy. I would like to find css solution, but thanks.

Comment: @flatlizard CSS solution would be using classes, but then again you would have to modify the class with JS still.